# data structure of hierarchy based data representation

Tags: javascript, html

[image]
I have (Hierarchy) data as represented above.

I need to

- **display this data(UI)**
- **search Name field**

Which data structure must I use to solve this problem?

**display this data(UI)**:
For UI, my plan is to have a list of buttons and as user clicks on a button it goes to next level. For example, initially two buttons 'John Software' and 'Bobbys automobile' are displayed. As user clicks on the 'John Software' it then clears the screen and displays contents inside 'John Software' i.e. two buttons 'Hans automobile parts' and 'xyz cloud solution' and so on..

**search Name field**:
Should be possible to search name field from all the levels. Example, user searches automobile and it should display "Bobbys automobile" and "Hans automobile parts"

I currently have a json data which then get parsed and loop through the objects to get what users wants(search not included). I think its wise to use an existing data structure if any to accomplish this task.

Please let me know if you need more information from me.

Comment: Is one of the keys unique?

Comment: Value of name field/key is unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You basically got three options that make sense:

1) A tree:

To display the data as a tree, it makes sense that the underlying datastructure is also a tree such as:

```
 const root = {
   name: "Har's holdings",
   code: "0001",
   children: [
     {
       name: "John software company",
       code: "0220",
       children: [/*...*/],
    },
    /*...*/
  ],
 };
```

So when displaying you build up the buttons based on `node.children` and if one of them is clicked, you set the node to that `node = node.children[clicked]`. Now for searching it makes sense to flatten the tree, which can be done easily with generators:

```
  function* flatten(node) {
    yield node;
    for(const child of node.children)
      yield* flatten(child);
 }
```

That allows you to get an array as:

```
  const nodes = [.. flatten(root)];
```

That array can now be searched easily.

2) A lookup table:

You could store the nodes based on their code, and the  store the childrens code inside each node so that you can get them easily:

```
  const byCode = {
    "0001": {
     name: "Har's holdings",
     code: "0001",
     children: ["0220", /*...*/],
   },

   "0220": {
     name: "John software company",
     code: "0220",
     children: [/*...*/]
  }
  //...
 };
```

Getting all the childrens of one node can be done as:

```
  const childNodes = byCode["0001"].children.map(key => byCode[key]);
```

To get an array of all nodes:

```
  const nodes = Object.values(byCode);
```

3) An array

```
  const nodes = [
    {
     name: "Har's holdings",
     code: "0001",
     children: ["0220", /*...*/],
    },
    {
     name: "John software company",
     code: "0220",
     children: [/*...*/]
   }
 ];
```

That can be easily searched, however to use it as a tree, you have to convert it to 2) :

```
  const byCode = {};
  for(const node of nodes)
    byCode[node.code] = node;
```

Which one you choose should depend on the way it is stored, you can then easily convert between one of the formats above on the clientside depending on the usecase.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I am going with second option :)